# I want to save a file in VB.net from the amount of tries a user has

Tags: vb.net, console-application

I'm a student trying to learn Console App .Net Framework and I want to code a random number between 0000 and 9999 (as a pin that you need to guess). Thus far I've had to set it as a random number from 1000 to 9999 as the system wont let me do 0000. Furthermore, I want to save the amount of tries the user has as a text file e.g. if the user tries 50 times, I'd like it to say

```
Username          Tries
```

I've tried `Randomise() Rnd(*9999)` and `X = EasyNum.Next(1000, 9999)` but then I can't compare unless I convert that to an integer.

```
Module Module1
    Dim Tries As String = 0
    Dim EasyNum As New Random
    Dim HardNum As New Random
    Dim Attempt As String
    Sub Main()
        Dim Difficulty As String
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to MasterMind")
        Console.WriteLine("Choose between Easy and Hard difficulty")

        Difficulty = Strings.LCase(Console.ReadLine)
        While Difficulty <> "easy" And Difficulty <> "hard"
            Console.WriteLine("That's not a correct mode")
            Difficulty = Strings.LCase(Console.ReadLine)
        End While
        If Difficulty = "easy" Then
            Easy()
        ElseIf Difficulty = "hard" Then
            Hard()
        End If

    End Sub

    Dim EasyGuess1 As Integer
    Dim EasyGuess2 As Integer
    Dim X As String
    Dim Y As Integer
    Sub Easy()

        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the easy difficulty")
        Console.WriteLine("You have to guess a 4 Digit number between 1000 and 9999")
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your guess")

        X = EasyNum.Next(1000, 9999)
        Console.WriteLine(X)
        EasyGuess1 = Console.ReadLine
        Tries = +1
        If Mid(CStr(EasyGuess1), 1, 1) = Mid(CStr(X), 1, 1) Then
            Console.WriteLine("You have 1 number correct, try again?")
            Attempt = Strings.LCase(Console.ReadLine)
            While Attempt <> "yes" And Attempt <> "no"
                Console.WriteLine("Enter either yes or no")
                Attempt = Strings.LCase(Console.ReadLine)
            End While
        ElseIf Mid(CStr(EasyGuess1), 2, 1) = Mid(CStr(X), 2, 1) Then
            Console.WriteLine("You have 1 number correct, try again?")
            Attempt = Strings.LCase(Console.ReadLine)
            While Attempt <> "yes" And Attempt <> "no"
                Console.WriteLine("Enter either yes or no")
                Attempt = Strings.LCase(Console.ReadLine)
            End While
        End If
        If Attempt = "yes" Then
            EasyYes()
        ElseIf Attempt = "no" Then
            EasyNo()
        End If
        Console.WriteLine("incorrect")

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
    Sub EasyYes()
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a new guess")
        EasyGuess1 = Console.ReadLine
    End Sub
    Sub EasyNo()
        Dim Save As String
        Dim File As System.IO.File
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to save your tries? Enter Yes or no")
        Save = Strings.LCase(Console.ReadLine)
        If Save = "yes" Then
            System.IO.File.Create(Tries, "C:\X\Code\VB\Challenges\Challenge 1\MasterMind Test")
        End If
    End Sub
    Sub Hard()

        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the hard difficulty")

    End Sub
    Sub HardYes()

    End Sub
    Sub HardNo()

    End Sub

End Module
```

When I try to save the tries, I get this:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "C:\X\Code\VB\Challenges\Cha" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'
>   InnerException
>   FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Which I don't understand myself.

Comment: You are calling the method `System.IO.File.Create` incorrectly. You have to create the file and then write the contents to that file. Take a look at the docs for the [Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.create?view=netframework-4.8) command.

Comment: To expand on JayV's comment; you are passing to create like this: `file.create(Int32, String)`. But if you look at the documention Jay provided you will see there is no overload of the function which accepts this sequence of arguments. The function always expects a `String` first and an `Int32` second, because you pass the string as the second argument, vb tries to convert it to an `Int32` for you, which of course doesn't work in this case because it's a file path. Thus you get an `InvalidCast Exception`. Regardless of that `create` is not the function to use here as Christoph pointed out.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: @Christoph 
i tried to do what you said i should, and i got an error message saying this http://prntscr.com/nuizrd - for the save file. I then also changed the file.write to creat, that gave me this error, http://prntscr.com/nuj2ni
I also added the "imports system.io" and that gave me this message http://prntscr.com/nuj101
i also turned on OptionStrict, thanks for the tip :)
Im still very confused about vb, my teacher is "too busy to help" and this is the hardest thing i've ever done myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments in line. Please read all comments. This program is still not working too well but I will leave it to you to tidy up.

```
Module Module1
    Dim Tries As Integer = 0
    'Use only a single instance of Random
    Dim EasyNum As New Random
    'Dim HardNum As New Random
    Dim Attempt As String
    Sub Main()
        Dim Difficulty As String
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to MasterMind")
        Console.WriteLine("Choose between Easy and Hard difficulty")

        Difficulty = Strings.LCase(Console.ReadLine)
        'AndAlso prevents the second condition from executing if the first condition is true
        While Difficulty <> "easy" AndAlso Difficulty <> "hard"
            Console.WriteLine("That's not a correct mode")
            Difficulty = Strings.LCase(Console.ReadLine)
        End While
        If Difficulty = "easy" Then
            Easy()
            'ElseIf Difficulty = "hard" Then
            '    Hard() 'Not implemented
        End If

    End Sub


    'Dim EasyGuess2 As Integer
    'Dim X As String
    'Dim Y As Integer
    Sub Easy()
        Dim EasyGuess1 As Integer
        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the easy difficulty")
        Console.WriteLine("You have to guess a 4 Digit number between 1000 and 9999")
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your guess")
        'X = EasyNum.Next(1000, 9999)
        'The next method returns a non-negative integer not a string
        'To get 0 to 9999 with leading zeros do the following
        'Returns a non-negative random integer that is less than the specified maximum.
        Dim X = EasyNum.Next(10000).ToString("0000")
        Console.WriteLine(X)
        'Console.ReadLine returns a String. You should Not assign a String to an Integer
        'EasyGuess1 = Console.ReadLine
        'Never trust a user :-) Use .TryParse to set the variable
        Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine, EasyGuess1)
        'This just assigns the value of 1 to Tries
        'Tries = +1
        'If you want to increment Tries
        Tries += 1
        'Let's compare apples and apples
        'If you just convert EasyGuess1 To a string and EasyGuess1 is 54
        'the string is "54" You want a 4 character string
        'If Mid(EasyGuess1.ToString("0000"), 1, 1) = Mid(CStr(X), 1, 1) Then
        '    'but you only compared the first character, what about the rest?
        '    'Mid is aroung for backward compatibility. It should not be used for new code.
        '    'The position Integer is one based which is not at all sympatico with .net
        '    Console.WriteLine("You have 1 number correct, try again?")
        '    Attempt = Strings.LCase(Console.ReadLine)
        '    While Attempt <> "yes" And Attempt <> "no"
        '        Console.WriteLine("Enter either yes or no")
        '        Attempt = Strings.LCase(Console.ReadLine)
        '    End While
        'ElseIf Mid(CStr(EasyGuess1), 2, 1) = Mid(CStr(X), 2, 1) Then
        '    Console.WriteLine("You have 1 number correct, try again?")
        '    Attempt = Strings.LCase(Console.ReadLine)
        '    While Attempt <> "yes" And Attempt <> "no"
        '        Console.WriteLine("Enter either yes or no")
        '        Attempt = Strings.LCase(Console.ReadLine)
        '    End While
        'End If
        Dim CorrectCharacters = TestInput(EasyGuess1, X)
        Console.WriteLine($"You have guessed {CorrectCharacters} correctly. Try again?")
        'Use the .net way. The framework is available to all languages in .net
        'so it will be easier to learn other languages.
        Attempt = (Console.ReadLine).ToLower
        If Attempt = "yes" Then
            EasyYes()
        ElseIf Attempt = "no" Then
            EasyNo()
        End If
        Console.WriteLine("incorrect")

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
    Sub EasyYes()
        Dim guess As Integer
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a new guess")
        'You are doing this twice ???
        'EasyGuess1 = Console.ReadLine
        Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine, guess)
        'EasyGuess1 will be 0 if the entry is other than an integer
        'Very nice bu this Sub doesn't do anything
    End Sub
    Sub EasyNo()
        Dim Save As String
        'Unused local variable and if you needed this it is a poor choice for a variable name
        'Dim File As System.IO.File
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to save your tries? Enter Yes or no")
        Save = Console.ReadLine.ToLower
        If Save = "yes" Then
            'Give the file name an extension.
            'When you pass (String, Integer) to the Create method, the Integer is the number of bytes 
            'buffered for reads And writes to the file.
            'Not exactly what you were expecting.
            'System.IO.File.Create("C:\X\Code\VB\Challenges\Challenge 1\MasterMind Test.txt", Tries)
            'Imports System.IO at top of file
            File.WriteAllText("C:\X\Code\VB\Challenges\Challenge 1\MasterMind Test.txt", Tries.ToString)
        End If
    End Sub
    Sub Hard()
        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the hard difficulty")
    End Sub

    Private Function TestInput(Guessed As Integer, RandString As String) As Integer
        Dim Correct As Integer
        Dim Guess As String = Guessed.ToString("0000")
        'A String can be a Char array
        'Here we check each character in the 2 strings for equality
        'and if true then increment Correct
        For i = 0 To 3
            If Guess(i) = RandString(i) Then
                Correct += 1
            End If
        Next
        Return Correct
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much
Secondly, im confused about a few things
What does parse mean/do?
whats the difference between += and =+?
What does ".toLower" do?
i dont know how to carry on a value e.g. if X is 5, then if the user inputs it again, then i set it to x=0  and make the user input x again, what happens is X doesnt stack (and i dont know how to go around that)
In class, we sorta covered arrays, but i still dont understand how they work

Comment: Interger.TryParse(String, IntegerVariable) is a Function available in .net. It tests the string to see if it can be converted to a valid Integer. If it can it returns True (the code here does not use the return value) and sets the IntegerVariable to the value. If the result is false the value of IntegerVariable will be the value when it was declared. If no value was provided in the declaration it will be zero.

Comment: `x += 1` will increment the value of x by 1. It is equivalent to `x = x+1`  `x=+1` will assign the value +1 to x. It would be the same as x = 1

Comment: Your code works, but it says access is denied ("System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\X\Code\VB\Challenges\Challenge 1\MasterMind\Saved' is denied.'"), how could i go around this?

Comment: Try using a path to the Documents folder. A user should have access there.

Comment: Missed the .ToLower question. It changes the string to lower case. It is a method of the .net String class. The Strings class and its methods are around for backward compatibility with VB6. For new code use the .net methods.

Comment: You can look up some of this with google. For example search "Integer.TryParse in .net". Look at the Microsoft Docs line. It can be a little difficult at first but if you keep at you will begin to understand. You can choose at the top of the page what language you want to see examples in.

Comment: The X question should be a new question. Put some code in your new question to demonstrate what you don't understand.

Comment: I looked up the Parse code and i think i understand it more now, thank you :)
I think i'll also start using AndAlso rather than and/or as it makes more sense to me
I also tried switching the path to my document path, my download and i even created a new user, that was as "public" as i could get it, but i still got the same error message

Comment: What does " Dim CorrectCharacters = TestInput(EasyGuess1, X)" do?
When i run it, it shows how many characters are the same, how does it do this? and could i incorporate this for other variables, not just for strings?

Comment: TestInput is the Function at the very bottom of the code listing. It has 2 parameters, an Integer which we passed the number EasyGuess1 (the user input) and a string which we passe X (The random number padded with 0's to make a 4 character string). Because it is a function (as opposed to a sub) it must return something; in this case it returns an Integer which is assigned to CorrectCharacters. This is a specialized Function just meant to interact with your code. Check it out at the bottom of the code to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues, but I don't want to spoil it for you.

I definitely recommend to put "Option Strict On" in the project settings, so you immediately see where there are conversion errors (a string assigned to a integer etc).

To save the file, it should be something like

```
If Save = "yes" Then
    File.WriteAllText("C:\X\Code\VB\Challenges\Challenge 1\MasterMind Test", Tries.ToString())
End If
```

(there are also File.Append... functions).

The Random class is a bit tricky, this is an object that provides random values and is not yet the random value itself. Always use the same random object for all different numbers, otherwise you might get the same number:

```
Private Randomizer As New Random(Environment.TickCount)
Private EasyNum As Int32 = Randomizer.Next(0, 10000) '0 to 9999
Private HardNum As Int32 = Randomizer.Next(0, 100000) '0 to 99999
```

The "from" value of the randomizer's Next method is always inclusive, the "to" value exclusive, for whatever reasons.

To increment a variable, the syntax is

```
Tries += 1
```

instead of "Tries = +1"

To write a number with leading digits, use might use

```
Console.Out.WriteLine($"The correct solution would have been: {EasyNum:0000}")
```

or

```
EasyNum.ToString("0000")
```

Comment: (Add an "Imports System.IO" on top of the script.)

Comment: @The Random class uses the system clock for a seed so, unless you have a special reason, it is not necessary to provide a seed. Good point about using a single instance of Random.

Comment: @Mary: Not sure if it is still the same, but in the past Random had a granularity of 1 second which resulted with a high probability in the same two numbers if two Random were created within a short amount of time (which of course is not recommended).